# When I use jQuery to set an element's opacity in IE6 or IE7, it seems to aquire "overflow: hidden". Why?

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, opacity

Consider this HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title></title> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
        div {
            position: relative;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #ff0;
        }
        span { 
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background: #f00;
            top: 100px;
            left: 100px;
        }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <div><span></span></div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Now let's add some jQuery code that sets the opacity of the containing div to any level:

```
$('div').css({ opacity: '1' });
```

The output is now this:

[image]

How can I avoid this? [Here's a test page](http://files.mattalexander.me/ie7.html).

EDIT: It happens in IE6 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you empty `filter` property, the problem goes away.

```
$('div').css('opacity', '1').css('filter', '');
```

or

```
$('div').animate({ opacity: '1' }, function() { 
    $(this).css('filter', '')
});
```